# How to create a catch all url in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to create a catchall url that starts with the prefix "angular". How do I do this?

I tried the following but does not work:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'angular'], function () {
    Route::get( '{catchall}', function () {
        return "YES!"
    } )->where('catchall', '(.*)');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'angular'], function () {
    Route::get( '/{catchall?}', function () {
        return "YES!"
    } )->where('catchall', '.*');
});
```

Be aware that you should put such route as last route because in case you have any specific route for example `angular/dosomething` it would also go to this catch all rule in case it would be after this catch all rule.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for the url "/angular"

Comment: @YahyaUddin Try `'/{catchall?}'`.

Comment: Yes thats the answer, which I also already posted. I submitted an edit on your answer, so once it goes through I'll delete my answer and mark yours as the correct one as it did help.

Comment: @Yahya it is good that you deleted your answer. Marcin clearly solved the problem so a little more than "it did help" in terms of credit was due. It's the principle. Anyway you've done the right thing now so all's fine.